# Using fileInput in shiny

Tags: r, join, shiny

I have a shiny app with data frame output and button to upload csv file which must left_join(merge) to x dataframe once I upload it:

```
x = data.frame(store=c("store1", "store2", "store35","store1","store3", "store4", "store2"),
               pos=c("pos1", "pos3", "pos5", "pos9", "pos14", "pos18", "pos24"),
               error=c("error1", "error2", "error4", "error3", "error2", "error1", "error3")
)
ui = fluidPage(
  tableOutput("myTable"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                accept = c(
                  "text/csv",
                  "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                  ".csv")
      ),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("contents")
    )
))
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  csv_df <- reactive({
    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
    # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
    # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
    # be found.
    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
  })
  req(csv_df())
  output$myTable <- renderTable({
    df <- left_join(x, csv_df(), by = store)
  })

}
)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I want csv file which I upload to left_join(merge) to x dataframe. However this error appears:

```
no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "c('reactiveExpr', 'reactive')"
```

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: It should be `df <- left_join(x, csv_df(), by = store)` (note the use of parenthesis on the reactive object)

Comment: @MrFlick no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "NULL"

Comment: Well, the `left_join` will only work when you've supplied a file name. When are you getting the new error? Maybe you want `req(csv_df())` so the join will only run when you've actually supplied data.

Comment: @MrFlick changed it(in question too), but still error: Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)

Comment: That `req(csv_df())` needs to be inside the `renderTable`: `output$myTable <- renderTable({req(csv_df()); left_join(x, csv_df(), by = "store")})`